# How to work with Zurb Foundation in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: zurb-foundation, visual-studio-2015, zurb-foundation-5

I created zurb project in Asp.Net MVC /Content folder by

```
foundation new MY_PROJECT
bundle
```

now I need to run **compass watch** for zurb project folder.
Is there way to automate **compass watch** run?

Comment: I used Web Compiler to compile my SASS. Works great. Wondering though...is there a reason you aren't using the Zurb Foundation 5.5 nuget package?